# "Undefined" is display with discount price in magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am using magento 1.8.1 and i am trying to display discount percent with sell price on frontend.

with the help of this site [discount](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33306/show-product-discount-percent-in-magento)

i am putting these code:

```
     <?php // Discount percents output start ?>
   <?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
     <?php $_savePercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price)*100); ?>
         <p class="special-price yousave">
      <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('You Save:') ?></span>
    <span class="price">
        <?php echo $_savePercent; ?>%
    </span>
    </p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

in this page: app/design/frontend/yourpackage/yourtheme/template/catalog/product/price.phtml

but after that the result is showing as like this:[image]

Now i am not able to find why "undefined" is showing here and how to remove this.

Please tell me how to remove this.

Comment: what is the value of $_finalPrice  and $_price?

Comment: thanks for reply, actually i am new to magento, so can you please tell me, where i am exactly see the value of price and final price?

Comment: just echo $_finalPrice and  $_price and see what comes

Comment: Ater echo $_finalPrice and $_price , prices will show in form of % but with undefined also.

Comment: first see the values of $_finalPrice and $_price separately, then for safety purpose cast both values to integer like, (int)$_finalPrice and (int)$_price

Comment: change  like this <?php echo $_savePercent."%"; ?>

Comment: Ayyanar: i tried this but undifined is still show with all the echo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73475/discussion-between-user2964674-and-ayyanar-g).

Comment: The error is not in the code you show, but in the code that comes after that. Shouldn't the 'You save:' text also show up? It seems blank right now.

Comment: 'you save' is working, only i have to change the colour after that it will show.

Answer (score -1):

I seen in your question image you need this effect on product detail page so have to edit media.phtml

```
app\design\frontend\YOUR_PACKAGE\YOUR_THEME\default\template\catalog\product\view\media.phtml
```

And in that you have to do same coding to get this value. you can make wrapper class which is override to product image with some dynamic text over product image like as you want.

You can use css like in [this page](http://techdem.centerkey.com/2013/01/ribbon-banner-css-transform-rotate-45.html)

I think its work...try in this way

Comment: Thanx for reply, but now i just want to remove "undefined". it is display along the discount percent.

Comment: this is a copy/paste from this post http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33306/show-product-discount-percent-in-magento